# Javascript enabled issue

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have some javascript that has the sprinkles radio buttons disabled at the start. IF you select an icing then the sprinkles should be enabled.
If the 'none' icing radio is selected then all icing radio buttons be be deselected and disabled.

So far I have:

```
function SetSprinklesEnabled()
{
if (document.getElementById("White").enabled)
{
    document.getElementById("HundredsAndThousands").enabled;
}


}
```

and

```
<b>Icing Flavours (Regular - 50c | Large - 70c):</b><br>

    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Icing1" id="White" onblur="SetSprinklesEnabled()">White
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Icing2" id="Pink">Pink
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Icing3" id="Blue">Blue
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Icing4" id="Yellow">Yellow
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Icing5" id="Green">Green
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Icing6" id="None">None

    <br><br>

 <b>Sprinkles (50c):</b><br>

    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Sprinkles1" id="HundredsAndThousands" disabled> Hundreds & Thousands
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Sprinkles2"  id="ChocolateSprinkles" disabled>Chocolate Sprinkles
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Sprinkles3" id="SilverBalls" disabled >Silver Balls
    <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Sprinkles4" id="Coconut" disabled>Coconut
    <INPUT type="button" value="Remove Sprinkles" onclick="RemoveSprinkles()" >

    <br> <br> <br>
```

This is the JFiddle to check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/39/

Comment: Instead of `.enabled`, use `.disabled`. Change your logic accordingly. You can both **get** and **set** this property, as it returns true/false, and can be set with true/false. Also, to know if a checkbox is checked (selected) or not, you use the `.checked` property, which can also be retrieved/set with true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like

```
document.getElementById("HundredsAndThousands").disabled = false;
```

Edit: see http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/45/

i changed the onblur to onclick and it works. There is an alert, added for testing. Don't do .enabled=true. Use disabled = false

Comment: try it on your test page. I am not sure how to get fiddle to work with pure js. There is always errors with getElementById

Comment: I think your setsprinkles is not firing at all

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to find why, is it something to do with the onblur?

Comment: It probably just does not fire for radio buttons, in this situation you can use onclick and do: click on button, first disable all then enable the one you need to enable (pass it into the function, so one function takes care of all buttons)

Comment: .selected is not for radio buttons, you just used .checked then went to selected, why? http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/46/

Comment: Got it working :) is there a way to add more conditions to this?
if (document.getElementById("White").checked == true)
{
}

Comment: you don't need the == true part, if you have more questions you should post a new question with a specific questions